# Why are nested promises not working for my code

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have never tried nested promises before this. However all my logic and the internet says that they should work. But below for my code this doesn't happen:

```
APIService.getData(Config + headerURL).then(function (response) {
            console.log(headerURL);
            console.log("header response from API", response);

            //Calling API for reference data
            $http.get(DataURL).then(function (refData) {
                console.log(Config + LeverReferenceDataURL);
                $scope.levers = refData;
                console.log("Setting ReferenceDataURL response from API", $scope.levers);


            },function (error) {
                console.log("API call for Reference data failed");
            });

        },function(error) {
            console.log("API call for header data failed");
        });
```

Here I am trying to make two API calls to recieve data from two URls. APIService is an Angular service that I have made to make http calls. Before this code, I was making both the calls using same service. Then I thought two API calls can't be  resolved with the same deferred object. So now I am trying the inner call using $http directly.

What I want is that the second call should be made immediately after first and all my code (below the above piece of code) should wait until both (or one of them) calls are successfully resolved or rejected.

Currently my code fails because before the second call's data arrives all the code depending on that data runs while the result of second call arrives later.

Am I wrong somewhere. What's the correct way of achieving my desired results??

Comment: because you didn't return a promise from the .then success.

Comment: I didn't get you Kevin, the .then() of first call is itself a promise right?? Can you slightly explain

Comment: `return $http(...` and `return refData`

Comment: Can you clarify this statement `What I want is that the second call should be made immediately after first and all my code (below the above piece of code) should wait until both (or one of them) calls are successfully resolved or rejected.`

Comment: @Chandermani I want to load both these API data before performing any another operation. So what I  mean is  I want a guarantee that these calls will be made one after other and only when both of them have been made, anything else on the page should execute

Comment: Where is the code? In controller?

Comment: Yes, the controller has above code somewhere at top..and the data received by these calls is used for other things below somwhere

Answer (score 0):

Unless your second API call depends on the data returned from the first API call, nesting like that only makes your code harder to understand. You can try something like this instead.

```
var firstPromise = APIService.getData(Config + headerURL);
var secondPromise = firstPromise.then(function() {
  return $http.get(DataURL);
});

$q.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then(function(responses) {
  var firstData = responses[0];
  var secondData = responses[1];

  /* Code here will not execute until both API 
     calls were successfully made */

}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("API call failed", error);
});
```

By defining the second promise with `then` after the first, it guarantees that the second API call will only happen after the first was successful. Also, you'll need to inject `$q` for this solution.

Comment: Yes my second call do not depend on data of first call. 
And as per you responses is an array that contain data of both API calls in same order. Also I believe this works for more than 2 calls as far as I write all dependent code in the .then() of $q.all()

Comment: Also what happens..when one of the call fails, or its promise is rejected

Comment: That's what `catch` is for. If any of the promises are rejected, then the `catch` code is executed with the error from that promise.

Comment: @Anid Thanks, 
Its save my lots of time

Answer (score -1):

Here's example in a form of a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wvjdpe

```
// Service
return {
    getData: function(url) {
        return $http.get(url);
    }
}

// Controller
service.getData(someUrl).then(function(someData) {
    service.getData(otherUrl).then(function(otherData) {
        // blabla
    })    
})
```

You need to return the promise(s) in order to chain them.

Comment: Question was about nested promises. Answer is about nested promises with actual working example. Using `$q` is one way to handle multiple promises but not the only one, and not always suitable. FTW, really?